# UICollectionViewCell still being configured when visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I am modally presenting a UICollectionView using a UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. The result I desire of one particular section of the CompositionalLayout is effectively the same behaviour as a UITableView. This section is of course used in conjunction with other sections with a different layout which I have omitted from the question/supplied code.

The problem I am having is that when I quickly scroll to the bottom of the section, revealing cells beyond the initial view, one or two cells appear to still be being configured once they have already appeared. This is not occurring all of the time though, and it is not always the same cell (indexPath).

I have been able to replicate this outside of my application in a very stripped down example. In the provided example, I have set be background colour of the cell to .systemPink, then .systemBlue, before the cell is returned. I have provided a link to an example GitHub repo at the bottom, but a general overview of the example app is as follows:

I have a main screen (name ViewController) with a large UIButton in the middle of it. Tap the button and a new UIViewController (SecondViewController) is presented modally.

The code for the SecondViewController which contains the UICollectionView is as follows:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    private var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
        setCollectionViewConstraints()
        
    }

    func setCollectionViewConstraints() {
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: SecondViewController.createCollectionViewLayout())
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
    
    
    static func createCollectionViewLayout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        let contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 16, bottom: 0, trailing: 16)
        
        // Items
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: .absolute(40))
        )
        
        // Groups
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
                heightDimension: .estimated(200)), //estimated 80
            subitems: [item]
        )
        
        // Sections
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.contentInsets = contentInsets

        // Return
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
            sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
            return section
        }
        
        let collectionViewConfiguration = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
        collectionViewConfiguration.interSectionSpacing = 16
        layout.configuration = collectionViewConfiguration
        return layout
    }
}

extension SecondViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        50
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        cell.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

In my full project I am using a custom cell and obviously doing a lot more, however I have stripped all of that back for simplicity. It may take a few times to scroll down and replicate, but every now and then you can see the flash of the initial pink just as the cell appears.

I understand that cells are dequeued and reused, but I am struggling to get my head around why the cell is being returned before it has been fully configured (i.e. set to its final background colour of .systemBlue?

Apologies if any of my terminology is a little off. Please feel free to download a working example of the example app stripped back version at: https://github.com/benhindle/CollectionViewProject.

I have also uploaded a short video of the problem at:
https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/575211828

Thanks for any ideas/help you can provide!

Comment: When do you reload the collection view?  And what does "revealing cells beyond the initial view, one or two cells appear to still be being configured once they have already appeared" mean?

Comment: Thanks El Tomato. I am not calling a reload on the collection view at all. Am I supposed to be doing this? Where would you suggest to call the reload? What I meant by "revealing cells beyond the initial view" was scrolling down to cells that were not visible when the view first appeared. As for the latter part, I meant the background colour was in the process of being changed from the original .systemPink to .systemBlue (this is just to demonstrate, in my full application the cell layout constraints are still being set).

Comment: I don't really see the problem after I changed the `cellForItemAt` delegate method such that the cells have alternating colors.

Comment: Sorry El Tomato, I am not following what you mean. How did you change the cellForItemAt delegate method?

Comment: if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
 cell.backgroundColor = .systemPink;
 return cell;
} else {
 cell.backgroundColor = .systemBlue;
 return cell;
}

Comment: Okay, yes, I understand what you mean. The intended purpose of the colour change was to indicate that the cell is still being configured (colour being set- I'm sure thats not the right terminology sorry) when it appears on screen. The purpose was not to have alternating coloured cells. Sorry for the confusion.